# How would the main and sidepot split in this situation?

Tags: rules, side-pots

This is suppose a timeslice stopped at the showdown, to calculate the pot split and side pots and all..

```
Player A: 200 staked, folded in earlier rounds (not eligible to win)

Player B: 600 all in

Player C: 600 called, winner

Player D: 300 all in

Player E: 200 all in, winner
```

Player C and E have won the hand, and the pot (total 1900) needs to be divided.

Since E has only 200 staked, lowest of all, the main pot should be 200*5=1000

Would this main pot be divided between C and E equally? 500-500?

Now the sidepot, 1900-1000=900, would this be divided too?

Or would the whole pot (1900) be divided? (since 1900/2=950 is still less than 200*5=1000 for E)

Also, had D won as well, how would the pot divide then?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've left out a crucial fact to answer your question. You stated "C and E won the hand" but did they have equal hands, or did E's hand beat C's (meaning C won by virtue of having more interest in the pot)?

If C and E had equal hands, then they will chop (split) the main 1000 pot, and C will take the  side pot completely.

If E's hand beat C's, E will take the complete main pot. C will still take the side pot.

If D had a hand that tied C and E's, then all three would share a third of the main pot; two would chop the first side pot, and one would take the remainder. If the order of hand rankings was E > D > C, three would split the main pot; two would chop the second pot; one would take the third pot.

Basically, to get any part of any pot, you must beat everyone in that pot to take it solo, or tie everyone in that pot to take a share divided by the people you tied. In order to be eligible for any pot, you must have money in that pot (the same amount as everyone else; if you had only some of the money then it would be two smaller pots so you participate in one, not both).